# Next 14 App Router pages from dynamic routes not generating when deployed on vercel but only work on localhost

Tags: deployment, vercel, production, app-router, nextjs-dynamic-routing

[image: file routing here]

Every Page generated from static routes works fine on vercel but not the one from [slug] page js

`{workshops.map((workshop) => (<Link href={`/workShops/${workshop.title}`} key={workshop.id} passHref> <PersonalCard workshop={workshop} /></Link>))}`

here is the link.workshops are from dummy data here.

`const SingleWorkshopPage = ({ params }) => {const { slug } = params; const workshop = workshops.find((w) => w.title === slug); return <PersonalCardPage title={workshop.title}></PersonalCardPage>};`

and this is the singlePage.

I have been searching for something sprcific but i haven't found anything yet.
The problem is that it works on localhost but on vercel all the other pages are ok except from this one from the slug.It dows not throw any errors however it just directs me to homepage.
params are all ok as far as i can understand. It is the first time deploy something using next 14 on vercel so i can't figure it out.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thnks!!!